# Rails apply a condition within a sort_by looking for value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on sorting a list of employees by their title with the following:

```
TAGS = {
'Region Manager' => 1,
'Region Sales Manager' => 2,
'General Manager' => 3,
'Residential Sales Manager' => 4,
'Commercial Sales Manager' => 5,
'Other' => 6
}.freeze

def sorting_by_title(employees)
 employees.sort_by do |x|
   TAGS[x[:title]]
 end
end
```

Works fine but...I also need to do an additional sort if an employee last name is Smith and needs to go before other individuals.

So I've tried doing something like:

```
return TAGS[x[:title]] unless x.last_name == "Smith"
```

Not working. It's erroring out on the show page with undefined method `each' for 2:Integer.

So my thought was I would build out another method to look for the last name.

```
def nepotism(employees)
 employees.group_by do |emp|
   case emp.last_name
   when /Smith/ then :moocher
   end
 end
end
```

So I tried then referencing it like:

```
return TAGS[x[:title]] unless x.nepotism
return TAGS[x[:title]] unless x.moocher
```

Neither of those work. Nepotism ends up with undefined method `nepotism' for # and Moocher ends up with the same. Then I realized a simple query would work a bit better:

```
def nepotism
 @nepotism = Employee.where(last_name: "Smith")
end
```

Is there a better way to sort_by a last_name if it matches Smith and THEN by the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice trick: in ruby you can compare arrays. And, consequently, use them as value in `sort_by`. They are compared element by element. If `ary1[0] < ary2[0]`, then ary1 will be less than ary2, no matter the rest of the elements.

```
 employees.sort_by do |x|
   [
     x.last_name == "Smith" ? 0 : 1, # all zeroes come before all ones
     TAGS[x[:title]] # your main ordering parameter
   ]
 end
```

This would work very well, if there were many Smiths and you needed to sort them by titles between themselves. If there's only one Smith, then @Björn's solution is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Combine them like this

```
employees.sort_by do |x|
  x.last_name == "Smith" ? 0 : TAGS[x[:title]]
end
```

You can do it in the database as well (assuming Postgresql here)

```
def nepotism
  tagstring = "array_position(ARRAY"+TAGS.keys.to_s.gsub(/\"/,"'")+", last_name)"
  @nepotism = Employee.order("last_name = 'Smith' desc, " + tagstring)
end
```